# Is there a better way to write the following CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
.navbar-inverse .nav > li > youtube-dialog > a {
    color: #999999;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    padding: 10px 15px 10px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none; /*underline*/

}

.navbar-inverse .nav > li > youtube-dialog > a:hover {color: #ffffff;}
```

Then I have:

```
.navbar-inverse .nav > li > video-server-dialog > a {
    color: #999999;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    padding: 10px 15px 10px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none; /*underline*/

}

.navbar-inverse .nav > li > video-server-dialog > a:hover {color: #ffffff;}
```

As you can see all that is changed in the second set of styles is the name of an element.

Is there a way to write this without so much duplication?

Comment: Give those `a` a separate class (like `.navbar-li-dialog-a`) and then just call by that.

Comment: Well, you can write the rule so that the properties apply to more than one selector (separate selectors with commas). `div, p { color: red }`.

Comment: `#selector-a, #selector-b, #selector-c { //do something }` Although if you're expecting to have more like these, then maybe create a new class and add styles just to this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `a` tags a specific class, and just declare the CSS code you have to that new class. Like so:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="dialog_a">test</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.dialog_a { /* some code */ }

.dialog_a:hover { /* some other code */ }
```